# How can I efficiently stretch a one-dimensional array to an arbitrary size without interpolating?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to stretch a one-dimensional array to an arbitrary size without interpolating.

Ex:

```
>>> my_array
*[0,1,8,4]*
>>> stretch(my_array, 7)
*[0,0,1,1,8,8,4]*
```

or

```
>>> my_array
*[6,3,7,1]*
>>> stretch(my_array, 10)
*[6,6,3,3,3,7,7,7,1,1]*
```

etc.

My naive approach does exactly what I want.

```
def interp(list, length):
   out = np.zeros(length, dtype=np.uint)
   for x in range(length):
        out[x] = list[int(x * (len(list)/length))]
   return out
```

However, this has proven to be extremely slow; I'm trying to do this dozens/hundreds of times per frame.

numpy.interp method works fine for a continuous function, but I'm trying to manipulate non-continuous data as well. (as in the examples)

numpy.repeat is close, but can only stretch an array by some whole number multiple.

Thanks for reading!

EDIT: To clarify, I guess I'm trying to do nearest-neighbor interpolation in one dimension.

Ex:

```
[ 5| 5| 7| 7| 7| 9| 9]
[  5   |   7  |   9  ]
```

I'm trying to get from the bottom array to the top, for any arbitrary size.

Each cell of the target array maps to its nearest neighbor in the input array.

Comment: Can you better define what you mean for stretching the array? Start repeating the digits left to right until the size matches the given one?

Comment: This is called nearest-neighbor *interpolation* :-)

Comment: Agree with the comment above, you want a NN interpolation. Is this is an image or 2D array, an FFT method would be very efficient. I'd look at canned routines with an NN option.

Comment: By "not continuous" do you mean a sub set of the array ? I'm not sure why numpy.interp wouldn't work. One brute force approach to simple get something done soon, would be to compile your custom method with a just-in-time-compiler like `weave` which will create a small C program and link it to a method. Should run a lot faster.

Comment: @wbg by "continuous" I'm referring to cases where the elements are (more or less) a function of the index, probably not the right word. Some of the arrays I'm working with contain image data, yes, and obviously bands of pixel colors are not functions as such.

Comment: Sorry this is a special case of resampling . I didn't read your examples very well. This seems like a brute force program and you have a decent looking answer for that. I still think a JIT to C might help with time to run.

Answer (score 1):

The exact logic is unclear, but a vectorial solution might be to use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and slicing:

```
my_array = np.array([0,1,8,4])

def stretch(a, n):
    return np.repeat(a, np.ceil(n/len(a)))[:n]

stretch(my_array, 7)
# array([0, 0, 1, 1, 8, 8, 4])

stretch(my_array, 10)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 4])
```

You can adapt the slicing part with your desired rule

Comment: What are your constraints? Have you tested this approach?

Comment: This is empirically slower than Yves' approach at small `n`s, but faster at larger ones.

Comment: @AKX this is expected, for small `n` you measure numpy's overhead, for large ones you benefit from vectorization ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of `m` indexes running from `0` to `n-1`, by the formula `k * n // m`, and generate a new list by dereferencing the initial list, using an implicit loop.

E.g.

```
[6, 3, 7, 1] -> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3] -> [6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1]
```

One-liner:

```
print([a[k * n // m] for k in range(m)])
```

Two-liner:

```
i= [k * n // m for k in range(m)]
print([a[i[k]] for k in range(m)])
```

If `n` and `m` are constant, you compute the indexes once for all. I doubt one can do much better.

---

OpenCV's `resize` does just that in the `INTER_NEAREST` mode. If done on a single image row, the overhead will probably be unbearable. If done on multiple rows, that might be faster.

Comment: This does work, and is faster, but still a fair bit slower than I need. I may need to write this method in C or something...

Comment: @CadenSnyder: can you precompute the index ?

Comment: You can make this about 20% faster as `[a[k // m] for k in range(0, m * n, n)]` 

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Yves method but using `np.linspace` to generate the indices.

```
import numpy as np

def stretch( arr, length ):
    idx = np.linspace( 0, len(arr), length, endpoint = False).astype( np.int64 )
    # endpoint = False to get the final index as len(arr) - 1
    # print( idx )
    # print( arr[idx] )
    return arr[idx]

np.random.seed( 1234 ) 
arr = np.random.randint( 0, 10, 10 )
arr
# array([3, 6, 5, 4, 8, 9, 1, 7, 9, 6])

stretch( arr, 15 )
# array([3, 3, 6, 5, 5, 4, 8, 8, 9, 1, 1, 7, 9, 9, 6])
```

Timings

```
%timeit [arr[k * len(arr) // 1000000] for k in range(1000000)]
284 ms ± 3.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit stretch( arr, 1000000 )
6.37 ms ± 18.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Stretching 10 elements to a 1,000,000 is 40 times as fast with stretch.